# Custom css does not overwrite properties in first css file

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with bootstrap, but I wanted to change a few of the colors around (navbar and buttons). I have an un-modified bootstrap.css, and a custom.css that changes all of the properties that I want changed from the default.

In my index.html, I link the default bootstrap, and then the custom css file.

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="bootstrap/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

I'm new to web stuff, but my understanding is that style sheets add to each other in the order they are linked. But when I open it in a browser, it doesn't use any of the changes specified in custom.css. Is my understanding wrong, or am I just going about this incorrectly?

Edits:
Original navbar-inner (bootstrap.css)

```
.navbar-inner {
  min-height: 40px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-color: #fafafa; /* #fafafa */ 
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f2f2f2); /*#f2f2f2 */
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#f2f2f2));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f2f2f2);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f2f2f2);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #f2f2f2);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#fff2f2f2', GradientType=0);
  *zoom: 1;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065);
          box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.065);
}
```

navbar-inner with a few properties modified in custom.css

```
.navbar-inner {
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #002f6c, #002f64);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #002f6c, #002f64);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#002f6c), to(#002f64));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #002f6c, #002f64);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #002f6c, #002f64);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #002f6c, #002f64);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#'002f6c, endColorstr='#'002f64, GradientType=0);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="brand" href="#">Test</a>
      <ul class="nav pull-right">
        <li class="pull-right"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li class="pull-right"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Do the first div classes also need to be changed? (They aren't)

I used [this tool](http://stylebootstrap.info/) to generate the custom.css file.

Comment: Can you include an example class that you're overriding in your `custom.css` and a sample bit of HTML where you're applying that class?

Comment: Your understanding is correct for the most part, but as is everything in the realm of code: it's not quite straightforward lol. Try removing the bootstrap css and see if any of your custom styles take effect at all, and us know..

Comment: try clearing your browser cache ? maybe it works ?

Comment: Clear your browser's cache. Also: Check in your browser's console (**Firebug** or **Chrome dev tools**) to see if there's any problem  with your webserver/webpage accessing the file.

Comment: Just put there some !important :P

Comment: Cleared cache and tried on multiple browsers, no dice.

Using firebug it looks like it accessed the file just fine.

Comment: Which style specifically is the one that isn't applying correctly?  I created [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uBzBu/) using your code to demonstrate.  (Added :hover to second styles to see the overrides)

Comment: Interesting. As it stands, it just shows the default header (grey, with formatting). If I remove the link to bootstrap.css, I get something identical to your :hover (as expected). 

The goal is to have it display the default header, but with the color changed and with the gradient removed. It would look like your :hover, but with the original formatting of the header bar. 

Right now I'm making a bootstrap2.css with all of the default bootstrap css and I'm changing the properties that I want in there. Seems a bit hacky to me, but it might work.

Answer (score 3):

Saying that CSS styles stack in the order they are applied isn't necessarily a correct one.  CSS is applied in order of importance, or specificity.

For example, consider the following HTML:

```
<ul id="testList">
    <li>Some data</li>
</ul>
```

If your first file has the CSS:

```
ul#testList { color: #f00; }
```

and your second file has:

```
ul { color: #00f; }
```

Then your first file has more specificity, even though the second file comes second in your markup.  The first style is more precise in its declaration.

If however, you change your second style to have matching specificity, then your second declaration will override the first.  Hope this helps!

Comment: The first selector is totally a bad habit and should not be used: `ul#testList` should **at least** become `#testList`.

Comment: @JeffNoel What's wrong with it? Selecting on an `id`, or selecting on an element *and* and `id`?

Comment: You are not selecting an element *and* and id; you are selecting an element **with** an id. Since `id` attribute should contain a unique value through your whole webpage (otherwise: [invalid w3c notation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)), it is totally useless to name the element's selector if you name its `id`.

Comment: It was just an example to explain specificity.  But curious, why do you say it is a bad habit to specify the tag with id as the declaration?  I hardly ever am that specific in my declarations, but I imagine it would possibly speed up the browser's rendering of the style, would it not?

Comment: I agree with you proposed scenario causing redundancy.  However, it is possible to have a CSS file that specifies styles intended for more than one page.  On one page you could have a ul#ID and on another page have a different tag with the same id, p#ID.  I agree that it makes for possible bugs, but I don't think it's a bad habit.

Comment: I kept thinking why the css I wrote doesn't override the previous one even though it comes later. The ``specificity`` part in this comment solved the case.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

It turns out that the tool I used does not change every property required! It should have also changed the .navbar-inverse class. After applying changes there, it works as expected.

In other words, both files were linked correctly.

Thanks for the answers though! I certainly learned a few new things.